# Opening a new window in Chrome from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, window.open

I have a asp.net website with C# code behind. I am currently using the following to open a window:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewHelpCall" Style="width: 180px;" runat="server" Text="New Help Call" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Width="135px" CssClass="buttonlink" OnClick="btnNewHelpCall_Click"></asp:Button></td>
```

In the Code Behind:

```
 this.Page.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.open('" + URL2 + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(decran).ToString() + "_ReqView','status=no,menubar=no,width=1000,height=700,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');</script>");
```

As you can see, its a half ass way of calling Windows.open, which has a problem with Chrome. Chrome expects a user action to precede the call. In this case, its a button action that calls the code behind.
Works in I.E., but not in Chrome. I apologize if this is a often repeated topic, but I think this should work, as it is called by a user action. And Yes, I disabled the popup blocker for the local host. ( another issue, some post say that Localhost urls won't open in Chrome, but I'm not sure that is true.

Thank You,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cant do it that way ! Even though the action is triggered by the on-click event, the way I injected the javascript doesn't count as a user action.

I ended up redesigning the gridview in which the button resides to use javascript.
Got the basic coding from here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/699912/Click-gridview-row-to-open-a-new-window

Thank You

Eric